# How can I keep handlers for different buttons in different classes in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, jframe

I have another problem with my program which is using JFrame. I am making a "cash machine" program, which asks user about his first name, last name, current account state and the withdrawal amount. I want to have two classes that implements two different tasks the program does. Class Card should ask user about all the data i said before, and then after clicking "Accept" button it should give a message box with information "Hello [user], you have withdrawed [amount], your current account state is [amount]." If user exceeds the "zero state" means that he wants to withdraw more than he has, program pops up a message box with decline information. The second class CreditCard does exactly the same, but allows user to make a debt up to 1500. I have two handlers : one for Card which works fine after clicking "Accept" button and second one for CreditCard which doesn't work at all. I know that the problem is with the proper inheritance, but I can't really solve it. It is important for me to store CreditCard handler in CreditCard class (if it's possible of course).

My code is as below:
Card class:

```
public class Card extends JFrame {

public JTextField firstName;
public JTextField lastName;
public JTextField state;
public JTextField withdrawal;
private JButton accept;
public JButton CREDIT_CARD;
private JLabel firstNameLabel;




public Card() {
    super("Cash Machine");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    firstNameLabel = new JLabel("First name");
    add(firstNameLabel);
    firstName = new JTextField("First name");
    add(firstName);

    lastName = new JTextField("Last name");
    add(lastName);

    state = new JTextField("Current account state");
    add(state);

    withdrawal = new JTextField("Amount of withdrawal");
    add(withdrawal);

    accept = new JButton("Accept");
    add(accept);

    CREDIT_CARD = new JButton("Credit Card");
    add(CREDIT_CARD);



    handler1 handler = new handler1();
    accept.addActionListener(handler);

}

private class handler1 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        String state1 = state.getText();
        int state2 = Integer.parseInt(state1);
        String withdrawal1 = withdrawal.getText();
        int withdrawal2 = Integer.parseInt(withdrawal1);
        int finalState = state2 - withdrawal2;

        // SHOWING THE FINAL MESSAGE BOX
        if(event.getSource()==accept)
            if(finalState > 0)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello " + firstName.getText() + " " + lastName.getText()  + " .Your current account state is: " + finalState);
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You are out of money on your debit account");
        }
        }       
    }
```

CreditCard class:

```
public class CreditCard extends Card {

public CreditCard(){
    handler1 handler = new handler1();
    CREDIT_CARD.addActionListener(handler);
}

private class handler1 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
         String state1 = state.getText();
        int state2 = Integer.parseInt(state1);
        String withdrawal1 = withdrawal.getText();
        int withdrawal2 = Integer.parseInt(withdrawal1);
        int finalState = state2 - withdrawal2;

        if(event.getSource()==CREDIT_CARD)
            if(finalState >= -1500)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello " + firstName.getText() + " " + lastName.getText()  + " .Your current account state is: " + finalState);
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your credit card limit has been reached");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I would do a refactoring using an MVC (model-view-control) pattern or one of its many variants.

Comment: I would explain what I meant by "doesn't work at all" -- there's no  specific question here.  This is not a service with which you can get people to debug your code, esp. not starting with figuring out what "doesn't work at all".

Comment: @rcook I mean, that there's no connection between the button CreditCard and it's implementation in the class CreditCard where the handler is located. That's why there's completely no action, same like I could add button to the design without writing a code for it. I have the handler, but I don't know how can I "connect" it with the button since the handler is located in the different class.

Comment: You could connect it by giving your Handler class (class names begin with capital letters -- use this) passing a reference into its parameter and using that parameter to set a field.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like your code is working fine.
Maybe you forgot to instantiate CreditCard instead of Card?

Answer (score 0):

Again, one way to do it is to pass in a reference, by giving your Handler class passing a reference into its parameter and using that parameter to set a field:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Gui extends JPanel {
   JTextField fooField = new JTextField(10);
   JButton button = new JButton(new Handler("Press Me", this));

   public Gui() {
      add(new JLabel("Foo:"));
      add(fooField);
      add(button);
   }

   public String getFooFieldText() {
      return fooField.getText();
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Gui");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new Gui());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }

}

class Handler extends AbstractAction {

   private Gui gui;

   public Handler(String name, Gui gui) {
      super(name);
      this.gui = gui;
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
      String foo = gui.getFooFieldText();
      String text = "Foo: " + foo;
      String title = "Foo Text";
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(gui, text, title, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }

}
```

Better to use MVC though